# Creating a Grid - What is an efficient way to do this

Tags: c#, matrix, grid

I'm  currently working on a little text-based game after watching the new Tron movie the other day. (as you do when you're a geek with to much time on your hands).

I've created a Grid in which objects can be placed and am currently finding that the creation of my grid is taking a long time.

I'm interested in how you'd impliment this and any design patterns, ideas, concepts etc that are useful for this type of thing.

Currently I have 4 main 'parts' that compose the grid.

First off I have the grid itself which contains an array of 'rows'

```
public interface IGrid
{
    GridRow[] Rows { get; set; }
}
```

A `GridRow` in turn holds an array of `GridCell`'s, each of which contains an IEntity array (every object that can be placed in a grid cell must impliment IEntity.

```
public class GridRow
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public GridCell[] Cells { get; set; }
}

public class GridCell
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public IEntity[] Entities { get; set; }
}
```

When it comes to creating the grid it takes quite a long time. Currently a 200*200 'grid' takes ~17 seconds to compose.

I'm quite sure there must be a much more efficient way to either store this data or create the grid using the current concept.

Any and all advice welcome.

**UPDATE**

Here's how I currently compose the grid:

```
public IGrid Create(int rows, int cols, int concurentEntitiesPerCell)
        {
            var grid = new Grid();
            Rows = new GridRow[rows];

            grid.Rows = Rows;

            var masterCells = new GridCell[cols];

            var masterRow = new GridRow();
            var masterCell = new GridCell();

            for (var i = 0; i < masterCells.Count(); i++)
            {
                masterCells[i] = new GridCell();
                masterCells[i].Index = i;
                masterCells[i].Entities = new IEntity[concurentEntitiesPerCell];
            }

            masterRow.Cells = masterCells;

            for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                grid.Rows[j] = new GridRow();
            }
            return grid;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause such a huge loading time unless the objects are quite large or there is something stalling the creating of them. You can do simple profiling to determine this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are creating a lot of objects for no reason? Why not just use a `List<List<IEntity>>` or a multi-dimensional array Entities[,]?

In any case I the code you have shown do not suggest the reason for the slow down. Can you post the code where you are actually allocating the objects?

Comment: Cheers @AbstractDissonance. I've updated my question to include the creation code.

Comment: Hey, since your going to be dealing with performance issues a lot why not get used to profiling? Here you'll be able to find exactly how long something is taking and find out why(usually ). Try it out and see, it's quite easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. After considering your reply I realise now that all i really need is a jagged Entities array (Entities[,][]). That perfectly acheives what I need and takes ~1 second for a 1000*1000 grid.